# PyInstaller exe gives cython error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an exe from PyQt5 code. It initially failed saying that 
the folder **"Projectfolder\jedi\evaluate\compiled"** is missing. I added empty folders from jedi onwards. It then failed saying that the plotly json files are missing. I added the plotly folder from site-packages. Now it fails with the following error:

```
File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 222, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._TSObject' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
[4380] Failed to execute script
```

I am now stumped and searching for similar issues on github and stackoverflow did not help much. My spec file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['start.py', 'process.py', 'compute.py'],
             pathex=['path to project folder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='projectname',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='projectname')
```

My code does depend on external csv data, but that is not called until a button is clicked. So at least the main form should display. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through the comments in the following link:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3079

Finally found the solution that worked for me. I needed to copy the pandas folder from site-packages to the dist. I guess it is something that could have been avoided if the spec file was configured correctly, but glad to see it working eventually!